# Не скролится меню

Tags: css

Есть сайт - https://karel-spb.ru/ . С недавних пор на мобильных устройствах перестало скроллится меню (нажимаем на бургер - открывается меню и дальше не скролится вообще). В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в свойстве `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` для обёртки всего сайта. Убрал и всё заработало.